# how to change the weight of a moderation state transition outside the database

Tags: 8, workbench

how can I change the weight of a Moderation state transition in code?  is it possible?  This is for Drupal 8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the weight in the admin panel, then export the yaml files with drush config-export

Comment: It seems that the 'moderation state' field is not configurable in the admin UI currently... was it before?